# How to get json value with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have this generated json

```
{"ListingId":"301191004942"}
```

I have this, but it's not working:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/29834729r8y9823';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                alert(val);
            });
        });
```

and I need the ID (number). How to get only that value?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need JQuery for this. Assuming you have access to the JSON string in your javascript, then you can you [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
var val = obj.ListingId;
```

With your edited question (and sample code which is using JQuery), try this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var val = data.ListingId;
});
```

Comment: It's not working. meaybe because of this json link? **http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx?id=43baf400-dbe1-4238-b608-38303e65faea&contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9** ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate as it is a single object not array.

Do like this:

```
var data = {"ListingId":"301191004942"};

alert(data.ListingId);
```

Your code will become:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

            alert(data.ListingId);

    });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/4Tp99/)

Comment: the url is from outside

Comment: still not working, maybe because of this? `var url = 'http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx?id=43baf400-dbe1-4238-b608-38303e65faea&contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9';`

Comment: first check by alerting data what is coming?

Comment: it is server side error, server is not returning json:``500 Internal Server Error - http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx?id=43baf400-dbe1-4238-b60%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B8-38303e65faea&contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9``

Comment: **http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx?id=43baf400-dbe1-4238-b608-38303e65faea&contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9** this is the good link, dunno why stackoverflow is changing the link when i post

Comment: yes it is weird i put in fiddle and it was not allowing there as well